# How do I debug a flutter app in vscode if the launch program is nested deep inside?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

### Problem in short

I'm trying to debug a flutter app using vscode and I get the below warning and the debugging stops due to the errors given at the end of this question. Apparently it is not able to find my dart sdk. But I have provided the sdk path in settings.

```
mobile_app/lib/main.dart:1: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:mobile_app/main.dart'.
```

***The problem is mentioned in this [medium post](https://medium.com/ppl-a-4-yuk-recycle/yuksharing-multi-app-structure-flutter-cb1ab547e0f2) but with no solution. You might have to translate the page to read it.***

### Further more clues

- This happens only when my main program is nested more than two levels deep.I have a deeply nested folder structure (given below). The `main.dart` file is in `foo/code/ui/mobile_app/lib` and the `.vscode/launch.json` is in `foo`. I've provided this path in `launch.json` for vscode. It works fine if I place my `.vscode/launch.json` in `ui` and open the folder `ui` in vscode or when I place it under `mobile_app`.
- This happens only in vscode. (The other IDE I tried is Android Studio)

### My folder structure

```
- foo
  - .vscode
    # launch.json
  - code
    + domain (this is a dart lib (shared code))
    - ui
      - mobile_app
        - lib
          # main.dart
      + web_app
  + design
```

### launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Jamsalon Mobile App",
            "program": "code/ui/mobile_app/lib/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Complete Error

```
mobile_app/lib/main.dart:1: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:mobile_app/main.dart'.

file:///C:/Users/random_user/Documents/app_development/frameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
file:///C:/Users/random_user/Documents/app_development/frameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///C:/Users/random_user/Documents/app_development/frameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
file:///C:/Users/random_user/Documents/app_development/frameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///C:/Users/random_user/Documents/app_development/frameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///C:/Users/random_user/Documents/app_development/frameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors are because your project is not being detected as a Flutter project (because of the deep nesting). When a Dart project is open, the plugin has to decide whether to go into "Flutter mode" and look for a Flutter SDK (and invoke `flutter` commands) or "Dart mode" (looking for a standard Dart SDK and using `dart` and `pub` commands).

For performance reasons, it only scans the top two levels of folders when making this decision. If you have a Flutter project nested many levels deep, it will go into "Dart mode".

My recommendation would be to use the multi-root workspace feature of VS Code so that the Flutter project is available further up (or as a workspace folder). For example, if you click File -> Add Folder to Workspace and then browser to your `mobile_app` folder, that should fix it. Unfortunately this experience isn't as nice as I wish it was (you'll now see `mobile_app` duplicated at the top-level of your Explorer tree) because of https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45470 (please add a  to that!).